# Cocos2d / Box2d CCRibbon Collision Detection

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone, box2d

I'm developing a game on iOS w/ cocos2d+box2d as the game engine, and am trying to add a CCRibbon (wherein the points get populated with touches), that I know how to, and to get that CCRibbon's shape linked up to box2d, so when an object collides with it (due to gravity), it bounces off as if it were a normal thing. Would anyone happen to know how to do this / give me alternatives ? 
Many thanks, 
Alexandre Cassagne

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take each point and create a thin static rectangular box2d polygon using the points + the adjustment to make it a shape.

```
for (int i = 0; i < ccribbon.points.length - 1; i++)
{
    int j = i;
    j++;
    int width = 2;

    Array ar = [];
    ar[0] = new b2Vec2(ccribbon.points[i].x, ccribbon.points[i].y);
    ar[1] = new b2Vec2(ccribbon.points[i].x + width, ccribbon.points[i].y + width);
    ar[2] = new b2Vec2(ccribbon.points[j].x, ccribbon.points[j].y);
    ar[3] = new b2Vec2(ccribbon.points[j].x + width, ccribbon.points[j].y + width);

    //create new static object
    b2Polygon b2p = new b2Polygon();
    b2p.setAsArray(ar);

    //do rest to add it to world etc.

}
```

of course don't copy that code exactly its just from what i remember and i'm also sure its a combination of C# and Actionscript 3. its kindof a not so pseudo code with lots of blanks you'll need to fill in. Why the comments are there :P.

Thats basically how i would do it though. My experience is only in box2d for flash though.

Comment: Thanks I'll try that then accept your answer. I'm gonna try to "port" it though as it's for ObjectiveC ;)

Answer (score 1):

Have you read this....http://www.raywenderlich.com/606/how-to-use-box2d-for-just-collision-detection-with-cocos2d-iphone

Comment: I have... and indeed for creating simple sprites which are predetermined (a box, a ball, etc...) it's fairly simple to determine the shape (square, round, etc...). However, there's no way to access the shape of a CCRibbon. Without points, I can't create the shape. Without the shape, I can't create the fixture.
Thanks anyways,
Alexandre Cassagne

Comment: This is REALLY good, but the problem is it isn't dynamic. Isn't there anyway to dynamically take any cocos2d shape and convert it into a box2d one ?

Comment: sorry..i didn't check for dynamic bodies...May be in their documentation you can find that

Comment: I wish, but Cocos2d's documentation is pretty sh*t if you see what I mean :)